# module 'tensorflow' as no attribute 'placeholder' please how can i solve this problem?

Tags: python, keras

Please I am a beginner in artificial intelligence. I use the latest version of tensorflow: 2.8.0. I'm trying to compile a code.py that uses several other python files from the projet. However I still receive this error: 'tensorflow module as no attribute placeholder'.

here is the output

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15200/1308516706.py in <module>
    160 
    161 if __name__ == '__main__':
--> 162     predict_roi_net()
    163 
    164 

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15200/1308516706.py in predict_roi_net()
     48     ###########
     49     # The model
---> 50     model = net_module(input_shape=(input_img_size, input_img_size, 1), num_outputs=1)
     51 
     52     model.load_weights(filepath=os.path.join(code_path, 'ROI', 'model_roi_net_epoch{}.h5'.format(str(epochs).zfill(3))) )

~\Downloads\base de données\CardiacMotionFlow-master\ROI\module_roi_net.py in net_module(input_shape, num_outputs)
     43         input_shape = (input_shape[2], input_shape[0], input_shape[1])
     44 
---> 45     input = Input(shape=input_shape, name="input")
     46 
     47     base_channel = 24

~\Downloads\jupiter\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py in Input(shape, batch_shape, name, dtype, sparse, tensor)
    173     if not dtype:
    174         dtype = K.floatx()
--> 175     input_layer = InputLayer(batch_input_shape=batch_shape,
    176                              name=name, dtype=dtype,
    177                              sparse=sparse,

~\Downloads\jupiter\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~\Downloads\jupiter\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py in __init__(self, input_shape, batch_size, batch_input_shape, dtype, input_tensor, sparse, name)
     82         if input_tensor is None:
     83             self.is_placeholder = True
---> 84             input_tensor = K.placeholder(shape=batch_input_shape,
     85                                          dtype=dtype,
     86                                          sparse=self.sparse,

~\Downloads\jupiter\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in placeholder(shape, ndim, dtype, sparse, name)
    515         x = tf.sparse_placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
    516     else:
--> 517         x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
    518     x._keras_shape = shape
    519     x._uses_learning_phase = False

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'

Please help me
```

Comment: Have you named your own script `tensorflow.py`, by any chance?

Comment: nope. the script name is predict_roi_net